# Move directory using Qt

Tags: qt, directory, move

I want to move a directory. My selected directory contains many sub directories and files.

How can I implement the same using Qt?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[QDir::rename](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#rename) does it in the most cases. Following example moves theDir incl content from source to dest:

```
QString original = "/home/test/source/theDir";
QString dest = "/home/test/temp";
QDir dir;
if( !dir.rename( original, dest ) ){
  throw Exception( "move failed" );
}
```

Comment: as a more specific use case, note that this doesn't work in case you want to move a folder from a shared network location to the current disk. in this case you have to copy the folder and remove it from the shared drive separately